# How to find cotangent?

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

Need to find a $3\cot(x+y)$ if $\tan(x)$ and $\tan(y)$ are the solutions of $x^2-3\sqrt{5}\,x +2 = 0$.

I tried to solve this and got $3\sqrt{5}\cdot1/2$, but the answer is $-\sqrt{5}/5$

Comment: This is a fantastic problem, by the way. How did you get your answer?

Comment: I am not so good with trigonometry. But I solved the equation and got: x1 = (3sqrt(5)+sqrt(37))/2 and x2 the same thing with other sign. Then I assumed that cotangent would be tan^(-1), so I reversed it as (2/(3sqrt(5)+-sqrt(37)). And then used the formula ctg(x+y). Maybe this is a stupid was, as it led to wrong answer. But I tried to do on my own before )

Comment: Using the letter $x$ for two different things in the same problem is infelicitous and potentially confusing. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Well, it is. Thanks for solutions.

Comment: @Severus: Doing things "inefficiently" doesn't give wrong answers. It looks to me like you computed $\cot(x)$ and $\cot(y)$ correctly; thus, the problem is either that you have the wrong formula for $\cot(x+y)$, or you made an arithmetic error when simplifying the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since by [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas) one has
$$\tan x+\tan y=-\frac{-3\sqrt 5}{1}=3\sqrt 5,\ \ \ \tan x\tan y=\frac{2}{1}=2,$$
one has 
$$3\cot(x+y)=3\cdot\frac{1}{\tan(x+y)}=3\cdot\frac{1-\tan x\tan y}{\tan x+\tan y}=\frac{3(1-2)}{3\sqrt 5}=-\frac{\sqrt 5}{5}.$$

Answer (score 7):

From quadratic equation given,

$$\tan{x}+\tan{y}=3\sqrt5$$
$$\tan{x}\tan{y}=2$$

So by the Compound Angle Formula,

$$\tan{(x+y)}=\frac{\tan{x}+\tan{y}}{1-\tan{x}\tan{y}}=\frac{3\sqrt5}{-1}=-3\sqrt5$$

So we have

$$3\cot{(x+y)}=3\cdot{\frac1{\tan{(x+y)}}}=3\cdot{\frac1{-3\sqrt5}}=\frac{-\sqrt5}{5}$$

Comment: @mathlove thx i fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
& x^2 - 3\sqrt{5}\,x+ 2 = (x-a)(x-b) \\[6pt]
= {} & x^2 - (a+b) x + ab.
\end{align}
Therefore $3\sqrt 5= a+b$ and $2=ab$.

Hence $3\sqrt 5 = \tan x + \tan y$ and $2 = \tan x\tan y$.

So
$$
\tan(x+y) = \frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y} = \frac{a+b}{1-ab} = \frac{3\sqrt 5}{1-2},
$$
and finally,
$$
3\cot(x+y) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt 5} = \frac{-\sqrt 5}{5}.
$$